# For each row in DF, check if there is a match in a vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R, and I want to check for any record in a vector that finds matches for the string in the DF. I can't seem to get it to work exactly right.

```
exampledf=as.data.frame(c("PIT","SLC"))
colnames(exampledf)="Column1"
examplevector=c("PITTPA","LAXLAS","JFKIAH")
```

This gets me close, but the result is a  vector of (1,0,0) instead of a 0 or 1 for each row

```
exampledf$match=by(exampledf,1:nrow(exampledf),function(row) ifelse(grepl(exampledf$Column1,examplevector),1,0))
```

Expected result:

```
exampledf$match=c("1","0")
```

Comment: `exampledf$match <-  lapply(1:nrow(exampledf), function(i) sum(+grepl(exampledf$Column1[i], examplevector)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grepl` returns a logical vector the same length as your `examplevector`.  You can wrap it with the `any()` function (equivalent to using `sum()` as suggested above).

Here's a slightly modified form of your code:

```
exampledf$match = vapply(exampledf$Column1, function(x) any(grepl(x, examplevector)), 1L)
```

Answer (score 1):

So here is my solution:

```
library(dplyr)
exampledf=as.data.frame(c("PIT","SLC"))
colnames(exampledf)="Column1"
examplevector=c("PITTPA","LAXLAS","JFKIAH")
```

pmatch does what you want and gives you which example vector it matches to. Use duplicates.ok because you want multiple matches to show up. If you dont want that, then make the argument equal to false. I just used dpylr to create the new column but you can do this however you would like.

```
exampledf %>% mutate(match_flag = ifelse(is.na(pmatch(Column1, examplevector, duplicates.ok = T)),0
                                         , pmatch(Column1, examplevector, duplicates.ok = T)))

   Column1 match_flag
1     PIT          1
2     SLC          0
```

Comment: I think `pmatch` could give an unexpected result if the match is not unique. E. g. try it with `exampledf=as.data.frame(c("PIT","SLC", "A"))` which should return 1, 0, 1, but does return 1, 0, 0 actually

Comment: It has to start with the letter, that is in examplevector. So "A" would not match.

Comment: Ah yes, a better example: `examplevector=c("PITTPA","LAXLAS","JFKIAH", "PUT")` and `exampledf=as.data.frame(c("PIT","SLC", "P"))`. `pmatch cannot decide which word for `P` is better: `PITTPA` or `PUT`...